# Paypalform submission is forwarded to the default paypal website

Tags: html, forms, http, post, paypal

I have a form that I want to submit to paypal. When I submit the form I don't get to the overview for the submitted product but I end up on the default page for paypal.

I started with `http://sandbox.paypal.com` but I tried the non-sandbox site too.

```
<form action="http://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" id="paypal_form" method="post" name="paypal_form">
    <input name="cmd" type="text" value="_xclick">
    <input name="business" type="text" value="some@email.com">
    <input name="lc" type="text" value="CH">         
    <input name="item_name" type="text">
    <input name="item_number" type="text">
    <input name="amount" type="text">
    <input name="currency_code" type="text" value="CHF">
    <input name="no_note" type="text" value="1">
    <input type="text" name="return" value="http://google.com">
    <input name="address_override" type="text" value="1">
    <input name="country" type="text" value="CH">
    <input name="first_name" type="text">
    <input name="last_name" type="text">
    <input name="address1" type="text">
    <input name="zip" type="text">
    <input name="city" type="text">
    <input name="email" type="text">
</form>
```

Since I don't get an error at all, I have no idea what is going wrong. I had cases when Paypal told me that I have to provide a city or something like that but now I just get forwarded.

**Note**: The Charles Proxy tells me that the form was submitted with these values:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the action address in your form.  You are posting to `"http://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"`.  Try using `"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"` instead.

Comment: brilliant. I wonder how I ended up seeing the shopping cart at one point though. Thanks!